# QtWebEngine cross orgin frame css

Tags: qt, qtwebengine, qwebengineview, qwebenginepage

Two different behavior when loading the HTML in qtwebengine page using setHtml and in the browser. Cross origin iframe overrides the css of the main div in web engine page.

```
<div class="tradingview-widget-container" style="-webkit-filter:invert(100%) !important; filter:invert(100%); !important;"> 
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-technical-analysis.js"
await>
{
"width": "100%",
"height": "100%",
"symbol": "%1:%2"
}  </script>
</div>
```

[image: Image when HTML file is loaded in chromium browser]
[image: Image when loaded in qweb engine view]

The second image is loaded using qwebengine view. I want to render the component in web engine exactly the same way as in the browser. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you got any error in the console?

Comment: @Zim No error in the browser console